# Which string is the longest

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, string-comparison, function-definition

My code:
What I'm trying to do is to input two strings, then return the longest one. If they're the same length then return NULL. Now, the code is just outputting gibberish and I cannot find out why. The function returns a pointer to the first character of the largest string. Then it goes through the while loop, and I'm trying to dereference the pointer and print out its value.

Note: I'm revising for an exam and we have to use only pointers and not treat strings as arrays.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

char* string_ln(char*, char*);
 
int main() {
    char str1[20];
    char str2[20];
    char* length;
   
    scanf("%s%s", str1, str2);
   
    length = string_ln(str1, str2);
   
    while (length != '\0') {
        printf("%c", *length);
        length++;
    }
}
 
char* string_ln(char*p1, char*p2) {
    int count1 = 0;
    while (*p1 != '\0') {
        count1++;
        p1++;
    }
   
    int count2 = 0;
    while (*p2 != '\0') {
        count2++;
        p2++;
    }
   
    if (count1 > count2) {
        return p1;
    }
    else if (count2 > count1) {
        return p2;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're incrementing both p1 and p2 in your string_ln function and then you return one of them later, so it is now pointing at the end of the string, not the beginning. Also, is there a reason you cannot use strlen? Also, `length` is a bad name for a pointer to a string.

Comment: @jarmod the requirement of my exams are not to use prebuilt functions at all

Comment: Yo can increase efficiency by checking the end of the strings "in parallel"... imagine one string is 3 chars long and the other is 1M long. Your posted function checks about 1,000,003 characters when about 7 or 8 should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here. First, you're modifying `p1` and `p2` in the function, so you won't actually return a pointer to the beginning of the largest string, but to its end. One way to avoid this is to iterate over copies of `p1` and `p2`:

```c
char* string_ln(char*p1, char*p2)
{
   char* tmp1 = p1;
   int count1 = 0;
   while (*tmp1 != '\0') {
      count1++;
      tmp1++;
   }
   
   char* tmp2 = p2;
   int count2 = 0;
   while (*tmp2 != '\0') {
      count2++;
      tmp2++;
   }
   
   if(count1>count2){
       return p1;
   }
   else if(count2>count1){
       return p2;
   }
   else{
       return NULL;
   }
}
```

Second, in your main, you're using the %c format string, which works for a single `char`, not a whole string. Since you have a string anyway, you can avoid a format string and just print it directly. Also, note that you should explicitly check for `NULL`s:

```c
int main() {
   char str1[20];
   char str2[20];
   char* longest;
   
   scanf("%s%s", str1, str2);
   
   longest = string_ln(str1, str2);
   
   if (longest) {
       printf(longest);
   } else {
       printf("They are the same length");
   }
}
```

Comment: If the intention is to calculate and compare lengths, you may not be able to use the functions in "string.h" but you could write your own "strlen" function. Breaking this functionality out into a separate function might be useful for avoiding bugs.

Comment: @Chris Agreed.I wanted to avoid restructuring OP's code and just point out the implementation problems in the given code

Answer (score 1):

In writing `string_ln` you iterate over both strings completely to find their lengths, and then compare those numbers. This can work, but you don't actually *need* to do this. You only need to know which is *longer*. It doesn't matter how much longer the longer string is.

```c
char *string_ln(char *str1, char *str2) {
    char *iter1, *iter2;

    for (iter1 = str1, iter2 = str2;
         *iter1 && *iter2;
         iter1++, iter2++);

    if (!(*iter1 || *iter2)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (*iter1) {
        return str1;
    }
    else {
        return str2;
    }
}
```

We simply need to iterate over both strings, until at least one hits a NULL character. Once we get to that point, we can test to see which iterator is NULL. If it's both of them, then they're the same length. If the first iterator is not NULL, then the first string is longer. Otherwise, the second string is longer.

The benefit to this approach is that we avoid unnecessary work, and make it much quicker to compare strings of very different lengths.

Comment: yeah, actually good point! But i doubt i can come up with these solutions in a exam.

Comment: Why do you think a solution like this would be unacceptable in an exam?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing to dereference the pointer. Instead of

```
while(length!='\0')
```

you'd need

```
while(*length!='\0')
```

That said, in the called function, you're reuring pointers after the increment, i.e., the returned pointers do not point to the start of the string anymore. You need to ensure that you return pointers which points to the beginning of the string. You can change your code to

```
int count1 = 0;
while (p1[count1] != '\0') {
   count1++;
}

int count2 = 0;
while (p2[count2] != '\0') {
   count2++;
}
```

so that `p1` and `p2` does not change.

Comment: oh that's a valid answer....but then nothing is printed....

Comment: Ah, that is because you're returning the pointer `p1` or `p2`, only when they are pointing to the null terminator.

Comment: got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
char * string_ln( const char *, const char * );
```

because the passed strings are not being changed within the function.

You are returning from the function the already modified pointer p1 or p2 that is being changed in one of the while loops

```
while (*p1 != '\0') {
   count1++;
   p1++;
}

while (*p2 != '\0') {
   count2++;
   p2++;
}
```

So the returned pointer points to the terminating zero `'\0'` of a string.

Moreover in main before this while loop

length = string_ln(str1, str2);

while(length!='\0'){
printf("%c", *length);
length++;
}

you are not checking whether the pointer `length` is equal to `NULL`. As a result the program can invoke undefined behavior.

The function itself can be defined the following way using only pointers.

```
char * string_ln( const char *p1, const char *p2 )
{
    const char *s1 = p1;
    const char *s2 = p2;

    while ( *s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0' )
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }

    if ( *s1 == *s2 )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if ( *s1 == '\0' )
    {
        return ( char * )p2;
    }
    else
    {
        return ( char * )p1;
    }        
}
```

and in main you need to write

```
char *length = string_ln( str1, str2 );

if ( length != NULL )
{
    while ( *length )
    printf( "%c", *length++ );
}
```

Pay attention to that the return type of the function is `char *` instead of `const char *`. It is because in C there is no function overloading and the returned pointer can point to a constant string or to a non-constant string. It is a general convention in C for declaring string functions.